# Eloquent: get related model with aliases

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a view where a related model property gets displayed.

```
{{ $product->category->title_en }}
```

I'd rather put this like

```
{{ $product->category->title }}
```

And make the locale selection in my controller.

For example with the main model:

View:

```
{{ $product->title }}
```

Controller:

```
if ($locale === 'en') {
    $product = Product::where(id of something)->get([
        'title_en AS title'
    ])
}
```

How can I set aliases for the related?
Or is there a better option?

Comment: From where you get the `$locale`
?

Comment: there's some awesome package that does al the locale handeling for you so you can write `{{ $product->category->title }}` and i'll always get the right localized title according to the locale set by the user requesting the page. https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable

Comment: Or you could wait for Laravel 5.4 release in january :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a helper function for this for my own project. As the locale is the first in all urls, I explode it and use it like this.

```
function translate($model, $column)
{
    $url = explode('/', Request::path());
    return $model[$column . '_' . $url[0]];
}
```

In the view file, I use:

```
 {{ translate($product, 'title') }}
```

Alternatively you can use `App::getLocale()` to get the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `select()` but you have to write names of other columns too in `select()`

```
 if ($locale === 'en') {
        $product = Product::where(id of something)
    ->select('title_en as title','col2','col3'....)
    ->get()
    }
```